# SagePay Direct: PayPal Payments - CreateBillingAgreement?

Tags: paypal, opayo

In the past I've used a zero value SetExpressCheckout with a BillingType of MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement (along with all the other necessaries!) to create a Billing Agreement without taking an initial payment*.

Is there a way to do this when integrating PayPal Payments with SagePay Direct?

I strongly suspect not, but am hoping someone might know different :)

*In this way a customer can switch payment method to PayPal for an upcoming transaction without having to pay early

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the flag BillingAgreement=1 with your transaction registration post, though for a standard payment transaction, this would require an initial amount to be taken.

I haven't tried it (so this may not work), but you might be able to use a deferred or authenticate transaction to initiate the billing cycle, but never actually release or authorise the transaction at the Sage Pay side.